# How to solve these two equations using sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I cannot solve these two equations using sympy

```py
eq1 = 20*x*y-10*x-4*x**3
eq2 = 10*x**2-8*y-8*y**3
solve([eq1, eq2], [x, y])
```

My answer is (0,0), (0,-i), (0,i), but the answer of book is (0,0), (+-2.64, 1.90), (+-0.86, 0.65).
book is calculus, 6th edition, James Stewart (section 15-7)

Comment: Checking manually, your solutions are all correct while those of the author are 1) trivial = correct 2) approximately right and 3) wrong. Sure there's no typo somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why solve isn't working here. These equations are cubic in each of x and y and since they are non-degenerate that should mean up to 9 roots are possible I think. I can find them by solving eq1 for x, eliminating x from eq2 and then solving eq2 for y. In one line that is

```
In [101]: sols = [{x: xi.subs(y, yi), y:yi} for xi in solve(eq1, x) for yi in solve(eq2.subs(x, xi), y)]
```

The full expression for some of these roots is complicated since they come from the cubic formula. I'll show approximate numerical values instead:

```
In [102]: for s in sols: print('(%s, %s)' % (s[x].n(3, chop=True), s[y].n(3, chop=True)))
(0, 0)
(0, -1.0*I)
(0, 1.0*I)
(-0.857, 0.647)
(-2.64, 1.90)
(-3.9*I, -2.54)
(0.857, 0.647)
(2.64, 1.90)
(3.9*I, -2.54)
```

Checking these roots with simplify or checksol fails for the `(+-3.9*I,-2.54)` roots so I'll demonstrate that they are probably solutions numerically instead:

```
In [103]: [eq1.evalf(subs=s, chop=True) for s in sols]
Out[103]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

In [104]: [eq2.evalf(subs=s, chop=True) for s in sols]
Out[104]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The procedure recommended by Oscar can be done automatically by using the "manual=True, check=False" flags:

```
>>> sol = solve((eq1,eq2), check=False, manual=True)
>>> [eq1.subs(s).n(2,chop=True) for s in sol]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> [eq2.subs(s).n(2,chop=True) for s in sol]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```